# Python 3.6 elif syntax error

Tags: python-3.x, syntax

using a nested if statement and my indentation seems correct thru out yet still reviving a syntax error.thank you

```
# FIGHT Dragons
if ch3 in ['y', 'Y', 'Yes', 'YES', 'yes']:

    # WITH SWORD
    if sword == 1:
        print ("You only have a sword to fight with!")
        print ("You quickly jab the Dragon in it's chest and gain an advantage")
        time.sleep(2)
        print ("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
        print ("                  Fighting...                   ")
        print ("   YOU MUST HIT ABOVE A 5 TO KILL THE DRAGON    ")
        print ("IF THE DRAGON HITS HIGHER THAN YOU, YOU WILL DIE")
        print ("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
        time.sleep(2)
        fdmg1 = int(random.randint(3, 10))
        edmg1 = int(random.randint(1, 5))
        print ("you hit a", fdmg1)
        print ("the dragon hits a", edmg1)
        time.sleep(2)

        if edmg1 > fdmg1:
            print ("The drgon has dealt more damage than you!")
            complete = 0
        return complete
```

## this is where i run into a syntax error

```
        elif fdmg1 < 5:
            print ("You didn't do enough damage to kill the drgon, but you manage to escape")
            complete = 1
        return complete 
        else:
            print ("You killed the drgon!")
            complete = 1
        return complete
```

Comment: The prior line, with the `return`, appears to be incorrectly indented, so you're left with an `elif` with no matching `if`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python elif: syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36389218/python-elif-syntax-error)

Answer (score 0):

Your return must be at the end of the if...elif...else statement. This works :

```
if edmg1 > fdmg1:
    print ("The drgon has dealt more damage than you!")
    complete = 0

elif fdmg1 < 5:
    print ("You didn't do enough damage to kill the drgon, but you manage to escape")
    complete = 1

else:
    print ("You killed the drgon!")
    complete = 1

return complete
```

Note that if the first if-condition is True, Python won't check for the subsequent ones.